# Generating partitions on range with procedures gets me Error Code 1654 MySQL, presumably type conversion issues

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Trying to create procedures that will create partitions on today's date or whatever date I will pass to it via bash script but looks like there is some sort of typization issue present here.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `add_new_partition`(mydate date, tableName varchar(50))
BEGIN
    
    set @val_less_than = date_add(mydate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);  ### example: PARTITION TEST_20210819 VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-08-20') ENGINE = InnoDB) ###
        set @partName = concat('TEST_', date_format(mydate, '%Y%m%d'));
        set @s = concat('ALTER TABLE ', tableName, ' ADD PARTITION(PARTITION ', @partName,' VALUES LESS THAN (''', @val_less_than, ''') ENGINE = InnoDB)');
        prepare stmt from @s;
        execute stmt;
        deallocate prepare stmt;
END
```

And then I have another procedure that calls first one multiple times.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'many_partitions'(mydate date)
BEGIN
    call add_new_partition(mydate, 'test_table1');
    call add_new_partition(mydate, 'test_table2');
    call add_new_partition(mydate, 'test_table3');
END
```

For comparision manual queries work fine

```
ALTER TABLE tableName add partition(PARTITION TEST_20210819 VALUES LESS THAN ('2021-08-20') ENGINE = InnoDB);
```

My first target to blame is `@val_less_than` variable but I can't figure out how to prove it\debug procedures. Any ideas?

Comment: `SELECT @s;` after you call this procedure will show you the SQL query. Since that is a user-defined variable, it keeps its value in your session after the procedure returns. Seeing the actual query it tried to run might show an important clue.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Error 1654. Partition column values of incorrect types.

Comment: The result of Select @s after execute statement is as follows: ```ALTER TABLE test_table1 add partition(PARTITION TEST_20220603 VALUES LESS THAN ('2022-06-04') ENGINE = InnoDB)```. Moreover, starting first procedure as ```call add_new_partition('2022-06-03', 'test_table1');``` works fine and creates new partition. replacing date with set @testdate = '2022-06-03' variable and (select @testdate) is also flawless. Looks like issue occurs when I pass some variables from one procedure to another.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30e03d4e303210ed83ed4442e329d066).

Comment: @wchiquito thank you for your effort! I will dig in different direction then, probably table structure or db user rights issues.